# Vim Word count and insert into current text

Tags: vimscript, counting

File `BATMAN`:

```
-2-3-4-6-8-10-11-13-14-16-17-18-19-20-21-25-29-30-33-35-36-37-43-44-45-47-48-49-50-51-52-54-55-56-57-58-59-60-61-62-63-64-65-66-68-69-70-71-73-74-75-76-81-82-83-85-86-87-88-89-90-91-92-94-95-96-97-98-99-101-102-103-104-108-110-111-112-113-114-115-116-117-128-129-130-131-132-133-134-135-136-137-147-148-149-150-151-154-155-156-157-158-159-160-161-162-163-164-165-166-167-168-171-173-174-175-177-180-184-185-186-187-188-189-190-191
```

File `ROBIN`:

```
-2-3-4-6-7-8-11-16-17-18-20-21-29-30-33-34-35-36-37-44-48-49-51-52-55-56-57-58-61-65-66-67-69-70-71-74-75-76-80-81-82-83-86-90-91-92-95-97-98-100-101-103-104-119-120-121-122-123-124-125-127-129-131-132-133-134-136-138-139-140-141-142-143-144-150-156-157-158-161-163-164-165-166-167-172-173-175-179-184-186-189-191
```

File `LOCUTOR`:

```
-4-147
```

I work in a translation company , and need to count the time that the actor speaks, and insert the count into the current file.

In my vimrc file I created this function:

```
fun! Abb()
    exe ":s/-//gn"
endfunc
```

How do I insert the number of word count manually. Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use external tools like word count `wc` in linux.

Comment: What does those number and hyphens represent? Which one to count as word?

Comment: This is the resume of a file,  the translator make 120 pages of all the movie,  then us manually separate loop of 20 second,  and the number above represent the loop into the actor speak in Portuguese. The money that the actor earn depend of this number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming for each actor, you only have a single line with the many hyphens and your cursor is on a line with the many hyphens, you can do it like this:

```
call append('.', "Count: ".len(split(getline('.'),'-')))
```

Of course you can now wrap it into a function, find the next line with hyphens in it, if the cursor is not on it or add some error management. That is left as an excercise to the reader :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian Brabant, you solve my problem, thanks